# How can I switch routes and still play audio

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, audio

I use Vue to play audio on a play page. I want the audio to still play after routing is switched. What should I do? I know that I can put the audio tag on the root page, that's one way to do it, but is there another way? It seems like it could be used for caching purposes, but I tried it and it didn't work.

```
<keep-alive>
    <router-view name="musicPlay" class="musicPlayer"></router-view>
</keep-alive>

<audio :src="this.url" ref="player"></audio>
```

If I put audio on the root page, how do I get audio's ref in any of the other components? Because I need to work on audio. currentTime. I tried. It seems that I cannot get this.$refs.audio in the child component. Thanks for your help.